# How to pass @Input string from one component to another

Tags: angular

I am able to pass data from one component ts file to another component HTML file. Please refer the code shown below:

```
export class TestComponent {

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-data',
  })

  @Input() data : string;
}
```

And in my another component HTML file I am able to use it like as shown below:

```
<app-data [data] = "Hello"></app-data>
```

My question is instead of passing data from another component HTML file, I want to pass it from another component .ts file. I found solution using service and emitters but I want to do it using `@Output()`.

Please let me know possible solution to do it.

**Edit Use case:**

I am trying to add a shared component which has some template in it. And the template gets updated based on the component where the template is used. There are lot of string messages that I am updating based on template requirement.

So the problem is if I pass all of the string from HTML, my code will look dirty. So I am looking for instead of passing it from HTML I want to pass it from ts file.

**NOTE:** Both component are at same level.

Comment: You want to pass `component.ts` file or pass whole `object` which holds property with current values ?

Comment: I want to pass Input parameter `data` from another component to test component from ts file instead of HTML.

Comment: You cannot pass data from one .ts file DIRECTLY to another .ts file with Input or Output. Those both require usage of templates (html)

Comment: ohh okay @Dino. Is there any tweak to do so? Or, I only have option that I have mentioned.

Comment: I think you should explain your use case more, you probably want to do something relevant, but perhaps there's a better way to do it if you add more information of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal Not that I know, services are used for that purpose.

Comment: Using the Input decorator allows for passing data from parent to child components as props while Output decorator allows for passing data from child to parent via EventEmitters. What is the hierarchy of both components? If they're in the established order for using Output decorator, what event will you like to bind to in the child component?

Comment: @MarcusLind I have added use case for my scenario. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want that but you could do something like following.

Child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `{{data}}`
})
export class ChildComponent {
    data;
}
```

Parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<child><child>`
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    // ViewChild lets you access your inner views.
    // But, be careful, it may take some time to initialize your view.
    @ViewChild(Child) childComponent: ChildComponent;

    // you have to do it within this life cycle method
    // so that you'll know your view is initialized.
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.childComponent.data = 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

**Based on your use case**

If you don't want to pass a lot of parameters through your template, you can define an input (let's call it settings) and pass a json object.

E.g.

Child.component.ts

```
export interface Settings {
    optionA: string;
    optionB: string;
    optionC: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `{{settings?.optionA}}`
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() settings: Settings;
}
```

Parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<child [settings]="mySettings"><child>`
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    mySettings: Settings;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.mySettings = {
           optionA: 'A',
           optionB: 'B',
           optionC: 'C'
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The second solution is helpful. Though I am looking for other options.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid passing your data through html?

Comment: Because I have about 15 strings, and each string is kind of paragraph.

Comment: Do you have them encoded in your class file? Also, you stated that you want to pass this through your ts file. My second solution does exatly that.

Comment: Yes. I think its fair answer. Thanks